# 'codeAutoRetrievalTimeout != null': is not true

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

i started learning flutter a week ago. am trying to build Authentication system with Firebase_Auth package and am get stuck with this error. the goal is to use firebase phone auth and with **codeAutoRetrievalTimeout** to take the sms code automatically.
here is my code

LoginScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:michot_2/screens/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final _phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final _codeController = TextEditingController();

  Future<bool> loginUser(String phone, BuildContext context) async{
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phone,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async{
          Navigator.of(context).pop();

          UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

          User user = result.user;

          if(user != null){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomeScreen(user: user,)
            ));
          }else{
            print("Error");
          }

          //This callback would gets called when verification is done automatically
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception){
          print(exception);
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Give the code?"),
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        controller: _codeController,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Confirm"),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: () async{
                        final code = _codeController.text.trim();
                        AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: code);

                        UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

                        User user = result.user;

                        if(user != null){
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => HomeScreen(user: user,)
                          ));
                        }else{
                          print("Error");
                        }
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
          );
        },
       codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
            child: Form(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),

                  SizedBox(height: 16,),

                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300])
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
                        hintText: "Mobile Number"

                    ),
                    controller: _phoneController,
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 16,),


                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text("LOGIN"),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final phone = _phoneController.text.trim();

                        loginUser(phone, context);

                      },
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

HomeScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final User user;

  HomeScreen({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("You are Logged in succesfully", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontSize: 32),),
            SizedBox(height: 16,),
            Text("${user.phoneNumber}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, ),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:michot_2/screens/LoginScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Michot Service',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: LoginScreen()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the confusion here?

Comment: **Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] Given String is empty or null**

Comment: This is a separate issue. Please post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

`codeAutoRetrievalTimeout` is a callback called when the code auto retrieval time is completed. It cannot be null.

If you don't want it, set it to this.

```
codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId){}
```

Comment: okay i made a bit changed 
`codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId){
          verificationId = verificationId;
          print(verificationId);
          print("Timout");
        }`

now it is saying Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] Given String is empty or null

Comment: @BessTilahun This is a separate issue. Please post it as a separate question.

Comment: @BessTilahun yes, please post it as a separate question.

Comment: i tried but **You can only post once every 90 minutes.**

Comment: If this answer is right for this question then accept.